# Problem using Camera2: Preview is fine but captured images are blurry and have banding artifacts

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I've been trying to set up an app that does the following:

1. Shows an image preview to the user in a PreviewActivity, where the user can click on a region and set the precise Focus Distance to a CameraSettings instance.
2. Then, in a CameraService, I'm disabling auto focus, retrieving the focus distance settings from CameraSettings, and capturing the image.
   My problem is the image is fine in the preview, but is blurry and has banding artifacts when captured.

This is what I'm doing before capturing the image:
`

```
     Float focusDistance = CameraSettings.getInstance().getFocusDistance();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_IDLE);

        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_ANTIBANDING_MODE_AUTO);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, focusDistance);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);`
```

Comment: Upon further investigation, I've found the following:
If I run this app on my S23 Ultra, everything works as intended, but if I run it on the S9 Plus, what I get is the correct retrieval of the focusDistance when capturing, but the images come out like if a higher value of focusDistance had been used (even though I'm setting LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE to that obtained in the preview, which is around 2.7).
Does this shed any light on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before turning off AF, are you verifying the device supports manual focus control?  That's not guaranteed, so you need to check the camera device's capabilities first.   If you just want to lock AF once you get a good value in continuous focus mode, you can use `AF_TRIGGER` for that.

Beyond that, antibanding on many devices can't handle flicker rates that aren't 50 or 60hz, and a wide variety of LED lights have flicker rates at other weird rates.  This isn't a problem if exposure times are long enough, but in bright conditions it can become a problem, where the exposure is short enough to reveal the flicker from the illumination sources.